# how to parse on column and add more records to a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have table tb1(col1, col2), col2 is varchar(50). For instance,

```
col1    col2
item1   abc
item2   a
item3   ed
```

I want to write a stored procedure to parse col2 and create a temp table like following:

```
col1    col2
item1   a
item1   b
item1   c
item2   a
item3   e
item3   d
```

Can anybody help me out here?

Comment: So you don't care about identifying the order of the characters from col2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the maximum length of the string, the easiest way is doing a simple union:

```
select col1, substring(col2, 1, 1) as col2
from t
where len(col2) >= 1 union all
select col1, substring(col2, 2, 1) as col2
from t
where len(col2) >= 2 union all
select col1, substring(col2, 3, 1) as col2
from t
where len(col2) >= 3 union all
```

If the length is never too long, you can do something like this to simplify the query:

```
select col1, substring(col2, nums.seqnum) as col2
from t cross join
     (select row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from Infromation_Schema.columns
     ) nums
where len(col2) <= nums.seqnum
```

Alternatively, you can do this in a while loop in T-SQL.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

You can get it using a single query

```
SELECT COL1,SUBSTRING(COL2,NUMBER+1,1) AS COL2
FROM   YOURTABLE T
JOIN   MASTER..SPT_VALUES M
ON     LEN(COL2)>NUMBER
WHERE  M.TYPE='P'
```

Comment: thats a column from the system table MASTER..SPT_VALUES

Comment: @GaolaiPeng: which version of sql-server you are using?